# Can anyone explain how to differentiate the Lambert W function?

Tags: derivatives, lambert-w

I'm interested in the differentiation of the Lambert W function $y = xe^x$.

I am unable to understand how to proceed for it.

Answer (score 3):

The Lambert W-function is not $y=x e^x$, it is the inverse function of $xe^x$.
Since:
$$e^{W(x)}W(x) = x \tag{1}$$
by differentiating both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $x$ we get:
$$ W'(x)(1+W(x))e^{W(x)} = 1 \tag{2}$$
or:
$$ W'(x)(1+W(x)) = \frac{W(x)}{x}\tag{3}$$
hence:
$$ W'(x) = \frac{W(x)}{x(1+W(x))}.\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the [product rule for differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).